# Integration approach for calculating the moment of inertia

Tags: integration

I must confess, most of the time when I was calculating moments of inertia I was using tables and the parallel axis theorem. Now I'm trying to **compute the moment of inertia by integration**.

The problem I am dealing with is a square "loop" which hangs by one of its corners. The rotation takes place so that the "opening" in the loop "moves" into or out of the screen. For better understanding see the picture. [image: Suggested calculation method]

Furthermore the loop has a side length of **l** (this is a lower case "L") and a total mass of **4M**.

Now my questions are:

1. Is the suggested decomposition of the square loop viable and correct?
2. What is the best method to calculate the moment of inertia of thin beam which rotates under an angle $\theta$ to the axis of rotation.

For calculating the moment of inertia of a thin beam which rotates under an angle $\theta$ to the axis of rotation I used two approaches, but I failed with both of them in calculating the final result. Which should be $\frac{2}{3} M_{total}l^2$. These approaches were:

**First approach:** Using the equation

$$I = \int r^2dm$$

With $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ expressing $dm$ as $dm = M \frac{dr}{l} = M \frac{\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}}{l}$. This yields in:

$$I = M \int (x^2+y^2) \frac{\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}}{l}$$

This equation can be simplified if we square both sides in ordered to integrate. But still, after this we have a squared differential... Is this correct at all, if yes how do i solve this integral?

**Second approach:** Using the tensor of inertia, we take the equation for the rotation around the canonical y-axis
$$
I = \varrho \int\int\int (x^2 + z^2) dz dy dx
$$

But here I don't really know what should I use as the limits of integration in order to calculate the correct moment of inertia.

Comment: Change your integration variable to be $s$ along the wire.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork within the first approach?

Comment: Yes.............